# How do I enable core dumps for daemon processes on montavista linux?

Tags: linux, system, embedded-linux, crash-dumps, coredump

I am not sure if stackoverflow is the correct place for this, but since this is for embedded development, and I need core dumps, which are also for development, I figured that this was the best place to ask.

I am trying to enable global core dumps in such a way that every time a program crashes in a way which produces a core, it gets written to /foo/bar/core.  Every time a program crashes, it overwrites the old core file.  Currently I have tried the following:

Adding this to limits.conf

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
*               soft    core          unlimited
root            soft    core          unlimited
# End of file
```

Adding this to sysctl.conf:

```
# Core Files
kernel.core_pattern=/mnt/ffs/core
kernel.core_uses_pid=0
```

This did not work.  If I boot the system, do a `sysctl -p`, `ulimit -c unlimited` and then restart the processes by hand (without the init script), I get a core file in /foo/bar, but it has the PID appended.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the core pattern to not include any process dependent information, yet the kernel still wanted to append the PID, so I ended up removing that bit of code from the kernel, and everything works fine now.